# How to display sharepoint library in gridview using c#

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have created a sharepoint library and also enabled the ratings option.

So whenever end users go through the documents they can rate on it ( I have taken Rating stars)

Now I want to display that library using C# and the rating column should be editable and rest are not(In rating column only stars should display as it displays in Sharepoint Libraries).

May I please know is it possible or not?

I researched a lot for this and due to I'm new to sharepoint I dont have much idea.
I'm using sharepoint2013.
I hope I can get any positive response from here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a custom web part in visual studio and you need Office Developer Tools for SharePoint, you can check it here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220049.aspx

Now, you have your development environment ready, you can create a new SharePoint project, and create a new item and choose Web Part, this will create a user control and a .cs file.

In the user control you have many options

- Server Side, you will add an asp.net `GridView` and bind it from code behind, and you can use either Server Side Object Model which is not recommended or you can use SharePoint Client Object Model with C#, at this point you can get your data from your library, you can chekc this link to know how exactly you can do that https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912.aspx
- Client Side, in this method, you won't use Asp.Net `GridView`, you can use any client side plugin, for ex: jQuery datatable, then you will retrieve the data using either REST or JSOM (Javacript Object Model), once you get the data, you will bind it to the datatable and that is it.
  This is sample for JSOM https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201.aspx
  And this is for REST https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142380.aspx

In both cases, you will render the table as read only and only make the rating editable, you can use any jQuery star rating plugin, after the user choose a rating you can make either a post back or an Ajax request to which will call SharePoint using either SharePoint Client Side Object Model, JavaScript Object Model or REST

Comment: Dear sir,Thanks for providing me the information.
I will start working on it.